# Adding button to the user control using class method in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing a user control for WP7 application. I added the control to `MainPage.xaml` and I want the control to create the button from a class called MyButton using the method `Add_button_internal()`, but I can't to figure out how to do it.

When I try to use a method `Add_button_external();` which is outside the class `MyButton`, there is no problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class WindowsPhoneControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public WindowsPhoneControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // THIS WORKS FINE
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Add_button_external("button name"));

            // THIS DOESNT WORK :(
            MyButton t = new MyButton();
            t.Add_button_internal("button name");
        }

        public Button Add_button_external(string m)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = m;
            return btn;  
        }

        public class MyButton
        {
            public MyButton() { }

            public Button Add_button_internal(string n)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Content = n;
                return btn;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MyButton classes Add_Button_Internal method only returns a newly created button, you would have to add it to the layoutroot.childer collection to display it on the UI. So i think your problem is only that you forget to add the new button to the UI.

Comment: but when i want to add it to the LayoutRoot.Children, using LayoutRoot.Children.Add(t); it doesnt work and writes Error Argument 1: cannot convert from PhoneApp4.WindowsPhoneControl1.MyButton' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

Comment: That's because your MyButton is a simple class and not a UiElement. You could add to the UI the Button which is returned from your MyButton.Add_button_internal method.

Comment: You were right :) ... Adding LayoutRoot.Children.Add(t.Add_button_internal("button name")); solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: To add your MyButton class to the UI you will have to derive it from a UI control.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Can you please help me, how to create the button in user control directly in the Add_button_internal() method?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't in front of my computer. Actually you are creating the button there you are just not adding it to the UI. You would have to give a reference of the UI container to your class and then to use that reference to add the Button to it.